# Ckeditor/ django 2.0 admin body input disappeared

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I recently installed Ckeditor on django 2.0, turns out some of the css and js files are not loading properly, I manage to get Ck read the files but now my admin body input was disappeared. [missing-admin-body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhwVb.jpg)

As I am pretty new to django, I was wondering if I were doing anything wrong in the setting. (try to make a blog, url + generic view set up)

setting.py

>

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'personal',
    'blog',
    'contact',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'EST'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URLS = '/media/'


# sendmail setting
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'kai.peng@uconn.edu'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False 
EMAIL_PORT = 1025

#CKeditor meida.root, and other setting
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor/' %}"
CKEDITOR_FILENAME_GENERATOR = 'utils.get_filename'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_URL,'js/jquery.min.js')

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'awesome_ckeditor': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
    },
}
```

here is my blog/url.py
>

```
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
    from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
    from blog.models import Post
    from django.urls import re_path, path
    urlpatterns = [ 
                    path('', ListView.as_view(
                                        queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25],
                                        template_name="blog/blog.html")),
                    path('blog/<pk>/', DetailView.as_view(
                                        model = Post,
                                        template_name="blog/post.html")),]


And here is my blog/views.py

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog.models import Post
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.shortcuts import render


urlpatterns = [ 
    path(r'', ListView.as_view(
    queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25],
    emplate_name="blog/blog.html")),
    path('blog/<int:id>/', DetailView.as_view(
                                    model = Post,
                                    template_name="blog/post.html")),
                ]
```

And this is my model.py

>

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140,null = True)
    body = RichTextField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor')
    date = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128,null = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

this is the console view when I tried to refresh admin edit page
[console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X9Z0.jpg)

I am using a python 3.6X and Django 2.0, on a Windows platform.
here is the website response with the 'empty body'  [site response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaHQx.jpg)

I suspect theres problem on the db integration or model registration, not sure....

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Post


admin.site.register(Post)

# Register your models here.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was about installing required plugins, I added following line to CKEDITOR_CONFIGS but I forgot to download these plugins and put them inside static folder

```
'extraPlugins': ','.join(['codesnippet', 'prism', 'widget', 'lineutils', 'clipboard']),
```

I also specified plugin directories like this:

```
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"
```

BTW make sure plugin folder's name inside this directory is the same with plugin's name, as you download plugins as zip and then extract it, its name can be a bit different...

This was all I have done to fix my issue.